# MYSQL - Create single sql query from multiple query

Tags: php, mysql, entity-attribute-value

I am using MYSQL Adminer 4.8.0 4.8.1

I am trying to form a single query from below select queries,
is their any way ir can be done?

There are 4-5 queries so i am afraid

````
SELECT `value` from `core_config_data`
WHERE `path` = 'catalog/product/base_media_url';

SELECT `label`
FROM `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value`
WHERE `value_id` = (SELECT `value_id`
FROM `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery` 
WHERE `value` LIKE '%test%')
LIMIT 1;

SELECT `child_id`
FROM `catalog_product_relation`
WHERE `parent_id` = 9622
LIMIT 1;

SELECT `rule_price`
FROM `catalogrule_product_price`
WHERE  `product_id` = 9622
LIMIT 1;

SELECT value
FROM `catalog_product_entity_decimal`
WHERE `row_id` = 9622  AND `attribute_id` IN (SELECT `attribute_id` FROM `eav_attribute` 
WHERE `attribute_code` IN ('price','special_price'))

SELECT `value`
FROM `core_config_data`
WHERE `scope` = 'websites' AND `path` = 'currency/options/default' AND `scope_id` = 3';

SELECT e.sku,value from catalog_product_entity e
inner join catalog_product_entity_varchar v on e.entity_id = v.row_id and e.entity_id = 9622 and
attribute_id IN (select attribute_id from eav_attribute where attribute_code IN ('name','sku'));
```
````

It would be very very helpful, if i get single query for this. Not sure if its easy to do it. but i am quite new in mysql so not getting exaclty.

I have tried using `UNION` but that won't work.

I have tried

```
SELECT parent.entity_id AS parent_id, 
       simple.entity_id AS simple_id, 
       parent.sku AS sku, simple.sku AS simple_sku 
       ccd.value AS base_media_url 
FROM catalog_product_entity AS parent 
JOIN catalog_product_super_link AS link ON parent.row_id = link.parent_id 
JOIN catalog_product_entity AS simple ON link.product_id = simple.entity_id 
LEFT JOIN core_config_data AS ccd ON path = 'catalog/product/base_media_url' 
WHERE parent.entity_id IN (9244) LIMIT 1
```

but it is not working.

Comment: for what you have **tried**, you can use conditionals only in a function, not in the body of a functional component. See useEffect.

Comment: can you please suggest me fix ?
I am been busy with this since last day

Comment: I think you should take a look at redux or mobx. It seems to me that you're little confused about retaining the state of your app. Context or sessionStorage aren't likely to be the solution. 

If you're sure about using sessionStorage, though, make sure the global *window* object is accessible when you use sessionStorage.

Comment: I have updated question.

Comment: What would you think be the benefit of one big query of different sorts of tables and data? Maybe merge the `core_config_data` queries and maybe the three that only have `product_id` as condition. I'd rather stick with multiple smaller queries. Cache the output of all of them together if you need a performance gain?

Comment: When you say `value` LIKE '".$image_path."', do you mean `value = '$image_path'`?  If so the answer will be a lot simpler than if `$image_path` might have wildcards in it.

Comment: I see `value` being set by two statements and used by two others.  Is the `value` supposed to be used only in the next statement?

Comment: I have updated queries in question

Comment: @Piemol sounds like a great option could you put it as an answer if possible ?
the cache part i will check it.

Comment: What is the goal?  Performance?  Single query?  Something else?

Comment: Performance for sure & single query are in priority list

Comment: @RickJames please have a look at this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68404225/mysql-join-similar-queries?noredirect=1#comment120891419_68404225

Comment: it appears that some of your queries return a single value (or perhaps no  result sometimes) while others potentially return 0 rows or multiple rows and sometimes multiple values per row.  show what you want the results to look like, or this is not answerable

Comment: The multi-value results _may_ be practical to return as a single string via `GROUP_CONCAT(value)`

Answer (score 2):

Technique 1:  Combining scalars:

```
SELECT a ... LIMIT 1;
SELECT b ... LIMIT 1;

-->

SELECT
    ( SELECT a ... LIMIT 1) AS a,
    ( SELECT b ... LIMIT 1) AS b ;
```

If `a` is something like `COUNT(*)`, then you know that there will be exactly one result; hence the `LIMIT 1` is unnecessary.

If one of those subqueries might not return any rows, then you get `NULL`.

Technique 2:  A select can be used almost anywhere an expression can be used.  The above is, technically, an example of such.  Also...

```
SELECT ... WHERE x = ( SELECT ... ) ...
```

Again, the subquery must return a single row to make that possible.

```
SELECT ...
    WHERE x LIKE CONCAT('%', ( SELECT ... ), '%')
    ...;
```

That becomes something like this after the subquery is evaluated:

```
SELECT
    WHERE x LIKE '%foo%'
    ...;
```

(It is not efficient, but it works.)

These 3 are similar, but not necessarily efficient as each other:

```
SELECT ...
    WHERE x IN ( SELECT ... )

SELECT ... FROM A
    WHERE EXISTS( SELECT ... FROM B
                  WHERE B.x = A.x )

SELECT ... FROM A JOIN B ON B.x = A.x
```

This is similar but finds the matching items that are *missing* from B:

```
SELECT ... FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON B.x = A.x
    WHERE B.id IS NULL
```

`UNION` should be used for queries that have similar output:

```
SELECT x,y FROM A
UNION
SELECT x,y FROM B
```

That will produce any number of rows from A and any number of rows from B.  Duplicates are removed if you use `UNION DISTINCT`, or kept if you use `UNION ALL`.

`ORDER BY ... LIMIT ...` gets tricky.  `OFFSET` gets even trickier.

**Performance**

- Avoid `IN ( SELECT ...)` it is usually the slower of the three.
- Avoid leading wildcards in `LIKE`; see if `FULLTEXT` would be a better option.
- `INDEX(path)`, `INDEX(parent_id, child_id)` ("covering"), `INDEX(scope, path, scope_id)`; maybe others, but I need to see `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.
- Avoid EAV schema; it is bad for performance.  I added a link; see the many other discussions.  Also:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/eav and http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#speeding_up_wp_postmeta

Those items are *probably* more important (to performance) than combining the statements together.  See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Rick
I am trying it

Comment: @devhs - I added a section on performance.

Answer (score 0):

Write a Stored Procedure, then `CALL` it.

Declaration:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE foo(...)
...
BEGIN
    statement 1;
    statement 2;
    statement 3;
    statement 4;
    statement 5;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Invocation:

```
CALL foo(...);
```

Comment: Thanks for help, can you please update answer with reference the queries i added into your logic ?
I am not getting exactly how to put my query into logic.

Comment: @devhs - (1) Improve performance based on my comments in my other Answer.  (2) Specify what parameters are needed for this Stored Proc -- perhaps $path, 9622, '%test%'; other things?  What about `('price','special_price'))`?  Is this always the same, or might the user need to vary this?  If Admirer is like phpMyAdmin, then the stored proc is for _convenience_, not _performance_.