# Mysql - Join similar queries

Tags: mysql

I am using Mysql Adminer 4.8.0
Below are the four queries that returns data, i am looking for a way to merge these four query into one
as they have similar WHERE condition for product id.

Is ir possible to do so, need an example or answer that executes into one.

```
    SELECT `child_id`
    FROM `catalog_product_relation`
    WHERE `parent_id` = 9244
    LIMIT 1;
    
    SELECT `rule_price`
    FROM `catalogrule_product_price`
    WHERE  `product_id` = 9622
    LIMIT 1;
    
    SELECT value
    FROM `catalog_product_entity_decimal`
    WHERE `row_id` = 9622  AND `attribute_id` IN (SELECT `attribute_id` FROM `eav_attribute` 
    WHERE `attribute_code` IN ('price','special_price'))
    
    SELECT e.sku,value from catalog_product_entity e
    inner join catalog_product_entity_varchar v on e.entity_id = v.row_id and e.entity_id = 9622 and
    attribute_id IN (select attribute_id from eav_attribute where attribute_code IN ('name','sku'));
```

Comment: These queries works perfectly fine but i am trying to optimize it
so code looks much better

Comment: These 4 queries all operate on different tables, select different tables, and, other your perception of a similar `WHERE` clause, have nothing in common with each other.  I suggest leaving them as 4 separate queries.

Comment: Thanks for your opinion @TimBiegeleisen but i think its possible to do it in single query & that will be helpful as code will look better and performance gain.

Comment: I completely disagree with your comments, these are my thoughts.

Comment: I assume a single query of all these 4 queries combined will be ugly and better looking code doesn't mean better performance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MYSQL - Create single sql query from multiple query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67820049/mysql-create-single-sql-query-from-multiple-query)

Comment: can you please add as answer ?

Comment: @FaNo_FN but its possible right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*IF there is at most one result from each of them*, then consider:

```
SELECT
    ( SELECT `child_id`
    FROM `catalog_product_relation`
    WHERE `parent_id` = 9622
    LIMIT 1 )  AS "relation",
    
    ( SELECT `rule_price`
    FROM `catalogrule_product_price`
    WHERE  `product_id` = 9622
    LIMIT 1 ) AS "rule price",
    
    ( SELECT value
    FROM `catalog_product_entity_decimal`
    WHERE `row_id` = 9622  AND `attribute_id` IN (SELECT `attribute_id` FROM `eav_attribute` 
    WHERE `attribute_code` IN ('price','special_price')) ) AS cped;
```

That will produce a resultset of one row with 3 columns.  Try it.

I did *not* move the 9622 out of the queries; that would actually be more complicated and much slower.  However this technique is possible:

```
SET @id = 9244;

SELECT
    ( SELECT `child_id`
    FROM `catalog_product_relation`
    WHERE `parent_id` = @id
    LIMIT 1 )  AS "relation",
    
    ( SELECT `rule_price`
    FROM `catalogrule_product_price`
    WHERE  `product_id` = @id
    LIMIT 1 ) AS "rule price",
    
    ( SELECT value
    FROM `catalog_product_entity_decimal`
    WHERE `row_id` = @id  AND `attribute_id` IN (SELECT `attribute_id` FROM `eav_attribute` 
    WHERE `attribute_code` IN ('price','special_price')) ) AS cped;
```

Give that a try.

Also, I did notice that 9244 was on the first query instead of 9622.  Was that accidental?  If it was deliberate, then you need two SETs.  Or explain where the numbers come from.

I left off the last SELECT because it is returning 2 values.  That adds complexity.

Another thought...

```
CREATE FUNCTION RulePrice(INT _parent)
    RETURNS INT
    DETERMINISTIC
    SQL SECURITY INVOKER
BEGIN
    RETURN ( SELECT `child_id`
                  FROM `catalog_product_relation`
                  WHERE `parent_id` = _parent
                  LIMIT 1 );
END
```

(I don't know the syntax for creating stored routines in Admirer; look that up.)  Similarly, define Relation() and CPED().

Then the above select becomes

```
SELECT
    Relation(9244) AS "relation,
    RulePrice(9622) AS "rule price",
    CPED(9522) AS "cped";
```

If the `IN` list needs to be a parameter to the function, then the query must be constructed via CONCAT, PREPARE, EXECUTE.  Let's leave that for another Q&A.

If that 3rd SELECT might return more "value",

- You can't use a `FUNCTION`, or
- Change `value` to `GROUP_CONCAT(value)`

The latter might return 3 "values" thus:

```
1234,9876,23546
```

Comment: Thankyou very much for the suggestions & answer & knowledge
Yes the given answer by you works & it appears a single sql.